# How to make a Battle Sorcerer into a Jedi?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats

I’ve chosen a 3.5 UA Variant Sorcerer: Battle Sorcerer to make a character inspired by a Star Wars Jedi.

What feats and spells can help with standard Jedi abilities? Limiting sources to PHB, PHB2, Tome of Magic, UA, and anything Forgotten Realms.

Some common Jedi Abilities:

High jumping, telekinesis, good with a sword, suggestion, precognition, etc.

Comment: 1. Are you open to alternative class suggestions? and 2. What about battle sorcerer has convinced you it is the best choice for Jedi? It’s not a *typical* choice for Jedi.

Comment: Sure! I tried making a more open ended question a few weeks ago but it got closed for being too broad.

Comment: Psionics actually make for the best Jedi characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Battle sorcerer is kind of a weird choice for a Jedi. As a sorcerer, it’s Charisma-based, and Jedi are not usually terribly charismatic (particularly in the D&D sense, where it’s closely associated with passion and self-determination, which are things the Jedi largely eschew).

Not to say that battle sorcerer *can’t* do it—you could take *charm person*, *feather fall*, *jump*, *suggestion*, *telekinesis*, and so on. It’s just kind of a weird choice. And your weapon skills are pretty mediocre, which doesn’t sound very Jedi.

More typical choices are Wisdom-based, and have greater martial prowess. Common choices include

- Cleric, refluffed to be the Force rather than divine power. After all, Jedi *is* a religion.
- Psychic warrior, where psionic power is the Force. Could be replaced by war mind in a multiclassing situation. Ardent is also solid, since ardents are warrior philosophers.
- Swordsage, where the supernatural maneuvers represent the Force.
- Soulknife, because the mind blade is close to a lightsaber anyway.

Any of these makes more sense to me than battle sorcerer. Psychic warrior and soulknife get psionic feats, too, which can help a lot—Up the Walls is Force-enabled acrobatics, Deep Impact can turn whatever weapon you go with into something that really has the penetration that a lightsaber does, and so on. And swordsage gets a lot of the same thing—better even—in the form of maneuvers.

There are also options for psionic initiators—the Instant Clarity and Psychic Renewal feats are quite good—though there is no proper psionic–initiating dual-advancement prestige class. Could be a decent use-case for a soulknife dip—though your weapon will suffer as you won’t be able to improve it—or using war mind.

Finally, we can get to the realm of third-party and homebrew material. The [Sleeping Goddess](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?98409-Sleeping-Goddess-Discipline) discipline can make mind blades and perform other psionic tricks, to *really* turn a swordsage into a Jedi. Beyond that, the [Pathfinder soulknife](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/) has some improvements over the 3.5 one (which is very poor), though it’s still on the weak side. However, the [war soul archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/war-soul-soulknife-archetype/) is quite strong, and absolutely perfect for a Jedi. And, whether going with PF soulknife or the 3.5 version, a [*crystal hilt*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/equipment/psionic-items/crystalline-focus-items/#TOC-Crystal-Hilt) is literally a lightsaber, and can go a long way to improvign the otherwise-mediocre mind blade feature.

My personal choice, given these, would probably be a war soul, followed by a soulknife/swordsage with a *crystal hilt*. Actually, with the *crystal hilt* available, a dip in soulknife would probably be something I try to put into any build. Soulknife/ardent, soulknife/psychic warrior/slayer, soulknife/swordsage/war mind are all reasonable options there. Without the *crystal hilt*, though, I would probably drop soulknife altogether.

Comment: Master of the Unseen Hand is a great add-on prestige class for Jedi-types. And psionics can even qualify for it as written, oddly enough. Don't forget the *Stygian Bolt* power for your dark lightning effects. If you are going to allow a mindblade, then grab elements that add flaming, brilliant, and sonic damage to it for the perfect lightsaber effects. Also, consider the Athasian soulknife instead of standard or pathfinder soulknife.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to homebrewing your character, I think a Duskblade (PHB2) is a good base to start from. Good BAB, Tons of spells per day, but none that are high level. From there you could make him a Wisdom caster, rather than Intelligence caster.  Remove his armor proficiencies and make him add Wisdom to AC. Sense motive should definately be on his skills list.

Instead of arcane channeling you could give him a mechanic similar to an Abjurant Champion's (Complete Mage) swift abjuration, converting the casting time of certain spells from standard action to swift action.  Discuss with your DM spells that are appropriate for his spell list, as it could easily get out of hand without an eye for balance. Shocking grasp, lightning bolt, charm person, mage hand, telekinesis, etc.  Check out the bard's spell list for some good mind affecting spells.

As far as combat feats, I see jedi having combat expertise, power attack, and improved sunder (how many weapons, and limbs, get sundered in Star Wars?)